# my algorithm practice with TDD

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Hello I am a newbie to TDD style programming in c# and am struggling a lot for getting it right. Could you please let me know if I am doing this in the right way. I have followed a lot of tutorials but haven't succeeded. I get the theory aspect of it but when it comes to putting it practically I always fail.

I have this repository for practising tdd https://github.com/dev-test-tdd/AlgorithmPractice/. I have started writing all the algorithms from scratch to understand tdd. For example , I have this simple method to check if the given string is a palindrome or not.

Here is my test

```
[Test]
public void IsPalindrome3Test()
{
    var sourceString = "civic";
    var result = Program.IsPalindrome3(sourceString);

    Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
}
```

and the function

```
public static bool IsPalindrome3(string source)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = source.Length - 1;
    while(true)
    {
        if(min > max)
        {
            return true;
        }
        char a = source[min];
        char b = source[max];

        if(char.ToLower(a)!= char.ToLower(b))
        {
            return false;
        }
        min++;
        max--;
    }    

}
```

Am I right here when writing the test ? Please let me know if the approach taken is right. Any pointers for that matter would be great !!

Comment: Instead of `Assert.AreEqual(true, result);` you could use `Assert.IsTrue(result);`. Besides that your approach seems fine. Just make sure to write a negative unit test to ensure that the method under test doesn't always return `true`.

Comment: Why you Just dont check if the string is te same iterating trough all characters forward and backward

Comment: Looking at the example you have given, if you were doing this test first you should have a lot more tests as there are a lot more possible outcomes than what you have tested.  Basically I could pass the test you have simply by returning true.  Remember the key to TDD is to only write what is necessary for the unit test to pass.  That makes you have to write another one that gets you closer to your end goal.  @kai has a good example of this.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really TDD you're talking about. This is just a unit test. TDD refers specifically to the process of writing your tests before your code. You start out with the most trivial case, see the test fail, make it pass in the simplest way possible and then you impose some new assumptions by writing more tests. The point is that as your tests become more specific and cover more edge cases, the code becomes more generic.

There are many ways to do this and people prefer different levels of granularity. One version would be something like:

```
// Single character is always a palindrome
Assert.True(IsPalindrome("a"));
```

Which would prompt us to write the simplest possible code to make this pass

```
bool IsPalindrome(string input)
{
    return true;
}
```

This code isn't "correct" though (although it's correct for all things we are testing for at the moment). We need more tests!

```
// Two non-equal characters are not a palindrome
Assert.False(IsPalindrome("ab"));
```

leading to

```
bool IsPalindrome(string input)
{
    return input.Length == 1;
}
```

And so forth. Stepping through the whole process of implementing the full algorithm takes too long for an SO answer, I just want to show that it's an iterive process with short feedback loops where you constantly impose stronger and stronger assertions about how the code should work, and then you let the algorithm grow. There are plenty of videos on youtube about this, and books and blogs as well. Go check them out!

Last but not least, it's also important that we when our tests are passing make sure to "clean up" the code too. Making the code pass in the simplest way possible often leads to some ugly repetitions and such. When tests are passing we can refactor this while staying confident that our code still holds up to the assertions we made. It's important not to add more functionality when refactoring though, because then that functionality isn't written test first, which is the whole point of the endeavour.